# Same url for two different categories

Tags: url, category

please refer this url

http://www.utsavfashion.in/newarrivals/saree

Under the `NEW ARRAIVALS` category i have the subcategory named as `SAREE`, then `All new catalogs` is the subcategory of SAREE. Both category (`SAREE, All new catalogs`) page have the same url. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. An URL must be unique.
If you want this only for display purposes, you can modify the menu so that for a category that has the level X you should display the url of the first child if it has one. Or make the first child of a category with level X to have show the url of the second child...what ever fit your needs. 
This can also be done via javascript. It seams easier. Just parse the dom and change the url's  of `a` objects on depending on your needs.

Comment: yeah, Thank you for your response. Do you have an idea about to display grouped products into separate category page? (like these site)

Comment: @DRAJI. I don't really understand what you mean. Can you please explain in a few words by editing the question? Or if your issue is not related to this question ask an other one. but please explain as much as possible the expected result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458203/how-to-display-grouped-products-into-separate-category-page plz refer this site

Answer (score 1):

To avoid canonical issue the url must be unique. I also made this mistake and my website was penalized by google.