# Remove negative numbers in category URL in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created three categories name same in different categories.negative numbers add in category URL.How to find out? Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you share the URL which is getting formed

Comment: Hi,   http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/c/medicine-2 this is my site URL

Comment: Url is always unique so if you have same name, your URL key will need to add something to make it unique. Hence it is getting appended with -2, -3 etc..

Comment: my requirement is all URL keys are the same name it generates 127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/c/medicine this is my aim.But not add any negative number.Can you please help me?

Comment: This is not possible as per I am aware, however, if you could better explain why would you have such a requirement, then there may be a solution to your problem.

Comment: In my site all categories URLs are unique.But in my requirement, I have same categories name required in different categories In my project no negative numbers added.That's why I am asking.Can you please help me?

Comment: I am not sure of your requirement, but I think Using product attribute, and using attributes in Layered Navigation can be a solution to your requirement.

Comment: How to implement Layered navigation? can you please help me?

Comment: I suggest you have a research, see if it really suits your requirements, and hence post a new question if you have any doubts.

Comment: That is not a negative number, is hyphen with counter when you have same url key , this url may help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7150/same-url-for-two-different-categories

Comment: Do you want same URL too for different categories with the same name?

Comment: Hi @  Akhil Gupta,  yes .Can you please help me?